# Static background for CGContext

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation, core-graphics, cgcontext

this is my first question here, so hello everyone. I have spent some time now wrapping my mind around the following problem and could not come up with a solution. I'd be happy if someone could point me in the right direction.

I'm using **CGContext** to draw various layers of graphical representations of live data which should be refreshed at a reasonable framerate of at least 50fps. I want to use a static image as a background. Re-drawing this image using the context for every cycle significantly slows down the frame-rate. I thought about just using **UIImageView** to display the image once. The problem here is that I want to use the blendmodes provided by **CGContext** in order to achieve more sophisticated overlays than just setting an alpha-value for each layer. Since the **UIImageView** displaying the background image is not part of the context, it's not affected by the blendmodes. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve the desired behavior without affecting the frame-rate too much? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A call to `CGContextDrawImage` with a `CGImageRef` with the the same size dimensions as the CGRect is fast. Setup a `CGImageRef` with the background image in code that gets run less often than every frame, such as the view's initialization code. If this background image is changing, build the image in the program logic code, not the draw refresh code.

The worst you can do is access the image from a file each time. Some time can be saved by not accessing the `CGImageRef` from within a heavier object. A call like `[someUIImageObject CGImage]` will add the overhead of a message send, whereas an access to a `CGImageRef` type ivar in the same object containing the drawing code will not.

If your source image is not the right size, first draw it into a `CGImageRef` at the needed size once, and reuse it in your drawing code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried using a **CGImageRef** right from the beginning. Before that I used **UIImage's** drawInRect: which also uses the corresponding **CGImageRef** to draw the image in to the context. Unfortunately, there is no noticeable improvement in terms of performance so I'll probably have to find another solution. Thanks again for your help.