# background image for CGContext

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Question: How do I display a background image underneath a **CGContext**?

I have created a view controller using the storyboard and placed a view with a full-screen background image.  Then, using the same view controller, I created a outlet to a UIView that has a **CGContext** where I draw a few lines.

Everything works except that the drawing takes place *underneath* the background image. (Suddenly I wonder if it's not the CGContext but the UIView that is the problem.)

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693977/static-background-for-cgcontext), but the solution makes it sound like the background image has to be constantly refreshed using **CGContextDrawImage** with a **CGImageRef**.  Which may be true, but a static image being constantly refreshed doesn't sound like a very elegant solution.  Thank you!

Comment: We are not fully sure what you're asking. Please ask a question, and provide some code of what you have tried in order for us to be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Create custom UIImageView subclass where you will draw your custom background.

Better to subclass UIImageView instead of UIView, because in this case you don't get problems with adding other views above this in Interface Builder.

Add UIImageView to your view controller, and change class to your custom class. Add all other views above.

Answer (score 0):

Question: How do I display a background image underneath a CGContext?
Answer: Set the color of the view with the CGContext to Clear Color.

That way the background image is visible as well as the lines that are subsequently drawn. Guess I kind of overcomplicated that one.

Thank you for the response Vitaliy.